# overlay conflict with query live search

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a onepager website i've a livesearch implemented which works as a overlay. The results are shown like this:

```
<div style="display: block;" id="LSResult">
<ul id="LSShadow">
    <li><a owl="sl23" slide="5" rel="sl23#6" class="clk_s">Team</a></li>
    <li><a owl="sl22" slide="9" rel="sl22#10" class="clk_s">Trust Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

The click-function looks like that:

```
 $('.clk_s').click(function() {
            alert("click");
            $('.search_ov').fadeOut();
})
```

Unfortunately, if i click on a result-link nothing happens. I don't know, but there must be some conflicts with the overlay/livesearch output - because if i testing without overlay, everything works.

Can somebody help me or know whats wrong?

thanks + best regards
thomas

Comment: Is it possible that some element in the overlay is covering the links you want to be clickable? Is there any live example or jsfiddle we can see?

Comment: thanks, you can check it on http://www.treuco.ch/index_dev.php (klick on "suche" top right and put "trust" into the search field.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. Hold on for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding to the click event on elements that don't exist yet. Since the event is bound on page load, but the search function renders the `.clk_s` elements way after that, they will never trigger the event handler.

One way to solve this is to bind the handler on a parent instead, say `<body>` for example, and fire the handler when the event was triggered on a child that matches your selector. That way you have bound only one event handler, and it will trigger on any `.clk_s` no matter when they were added to the document.

Changing your snippet to this should do the trick:

```
$('body').on('click', '.clk_s', function () {
  alert("click");
  $('.search_ov').fadeOut();
});
```

For more info on jQuery's `on()` function: http://api.jquery.com/on/